# How to retrieve key/value array from Bundle on Android

Tags: android, bundle, push

I'm trying to retrieve data from "extra" key:

```
Bundle[
 {from=1058706545539,
  extra={
   "ty":"msg",
   "d":"sec":1425242647,"usec":763000},
   "iL":"86777e87a574c3f068f6525e",
   "tU":"7e0a9dbbd1d6ee1795d64fdf",
   "iP":"4f26e5f78d042e2224688ed7",
   "iM":"dd83db95e764b103b4fec99e"},
  message=Oi , 
  android.support.content.wakelockid=1, 
  collapse_key=do_not_collapse
 }]
```

If it was JSon I'd use JSONObject, I don't know how to retrieve the the whole "extra" on a HashMap structure. So that I can use something like that:

```
String ty = extra.getString("ty");
```

I receive this bundle from Push Notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the string, then make it a JSON Object:

```
String json = extra.getStringExtra("extra");
```

Then:

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(json);
```